# Guidance on Patterns and recommendations on achieving database Atomicity in distributed architecture (microservices)

Tags: microservices, distributed-transactions

Folks, I am evaluating options/ pattern and practices around key challenge of maintaining db atomicity (across multiple tables) that we are facing in distributed (microservices) architecture.

Atomicity, reliability and scale all are critical for business(it might have been common across businesses, just putting it out there).

I read few articals about achieving but it all comes at a significant cost and not without certain trade offs, which I am not ready to make.

Read couple of SO questions, and one concept SAGA seems interesting, but I don’t think our legacy database is meant to handle it.

So here I am asking experts of their personal opinion, guidance and past experience so I can save time and effort without try and learn bunch of options.

Appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

**CAP theorem**

CAP theorem is the key when it comes to  distributed systems. Start with this to know if you want availability vs consistency.

**Distributed transactions**

You are right, trade offs involved and there is no right single answer. when it comes to distributed transaction it's no different. In microservices architecture Atomicity is not easy to achieve. Normally we design the microservices by keeping eventual consistency in mind. Strong consistency is very hard and not a simple solution.

**SAGA vs 2PC**

**2PC** it's very easy to achieve atomicity using 2 phase commit , but that option is not for microservices. your system can't scale system since if any of the microservice goes down your transaction will hang into abnormal state and locks are very common with this approach.

**SAGA** is most acceptable and scaleable approach . You commit local transaction (atomically) once done you need to publish the event , and all the interested services will have to consume the event and update their own local database. If there is exception or particular microservices can't accept the event data , it would raise compensation transaction , which mean you have to reverse and undo the actions taken by all microservices against that event. This is widely accepted pattern and is scaleable.

I don't get legacy db part. What makes you think legacy DB will have problem ? SAGA has nothing to do with legacy system . It simply mean if you have to accept the event or not. If yes then save it into database. If not then raise compensated transaction so all other service can undo.

**What's the right approach ?**

Well it really depends on you eventually. There are many pattern around when it comes to save the transaction . Have a look at CQRS and event sourcing pattern which is used to save all the domain events. Since disturbed transactions can be complex . CQRS solve many problems e.g. eventual consistency etc.

Hope that helps! shoot me questions if you have.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) - maintain one or more materialized views that contain data from multiple services. The views are kept by services that subscribe to events that each services publishes when it updates its data. For example, the online store could implement a query that finds customers in a particular region and their recent orders by maintaining a view that joins customers and orders. The view is updated by a service that subscribes to customer and order events.